# Django. Using Jquery Validate and ajax to make sure username is unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, jquery-validate

I want to use jquery validate() to make sure that there aren't users with equal nickname (or username, in my model it is called nickname, but it is the same).

the model field looks like this:

```
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True, null=True)
```

I want to use ajax, this is the javascript:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("checkNickname", function(){
    var nickname = $("#nickname").val();
    if (nickname == ''){
        return false
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/profiles/check_nickname/",
        data: {'nickname':nickname},
        success: function(response){
            if (response == "True"){
                return true
            }
            else {
                $("#help_nickname").text("Nickname already exists")
                return false
            }
        }

    })
    });

   $('#form_user').validate({
    rules: {
        nickname: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 75,
            checkNickname: true,
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    messages: {
        ...
});
```

and in views.py:

```
def check_nickname(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    nickname_new = request.GET.get('nickname', '')
    if Profiles.objects.exclude(user=request.user).filter(nickname=nickname_new).exists():
        return HttpResponse(False)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(True)
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profiles:login'))
```

This doesn't work, it behaves as if the username field contains an error and displays the error message all the time.

Comment: You do not need to write a custom method for this.  The plugin already provides the `remote` method for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) included in the plugin.

- The URL of your server-side function is the parameter
- You do not need to specify `data` because the field's data is sent by default.
- You do not need to specify `GET` because it's the default method.

```
$('#form_user').validate({
    rules: {
        nickname: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 75,
            remote: "/profiles/check_nickname/"
        }
    },
    ....
});
```

Your server-side function at `/profiles/check_nickname/` must `echo` or `return` `true` when you want validation to pass.  It must `echo` or `return` `false` or a JSON string when you want validation to fail.  The JSON string will become the error message if you use it, otherwise, the default error message will be shown.

> The serverside resource is called via `jQuery.ajax` (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a `GET` parameter. The response is evaluated as
>   `JSON` and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`,
>   `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or
>   a string, eg. `"That name is already taken, try peter123 instead"` to
>   display as the error message.

---

**SIDE-NOTE to answer why your custom solution is broken:**

**Quote OP:**

> "This doesn't work, it behaves as if the username field contains an error and displays the error message all the time."

That's because you're not using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) properly.  By inserting your message text into an element, you're manually bypassing how the plugin automatically creates and displays error messages.

The custom error message is supposed to be the third parameter, *after* the entire function...

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkNickname", function(){ // 1st, NAME for method
    // your validation function here               // 2nd, LOGIC for method
}, "Nickname already exists");                     // 3rd, ERROR MESSAGE for method
```

Then the plugin will know how & when to automatically toggle the message.  If the message is in the wrong place, use [standard `.validate()` options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) such as `errorPlacement`, `errorElement`, etc. to customize it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. But I am getting a weird error, the user has to submit the form twice before it actually gets saved. The first time the user hits "submit" it makes the ajax call to the remote nickname validation, the second time, it sends the form. :/ . Should I describe this in a separate question? or is there a simple reason why this could happen?

Comment: @alejoss, you're simply supposed to call `.validate()` within the DOM ready handler function.  `.validate()` should not be inside of any `submit` or `click` handlers.  This is the most common reason needing to click submit twice with this plugin.  Otherwise, open a new question and include all relevant code.